# Install a gem from a downloaded tar or zip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First let me say I cannot do gem install, I don't know why. Probably because I live in China and the firewall random things.

So I have to locally install gems. For example, i want to install this gem riddle. But this gem downloads as a tar or zip and when i open it it is a folder not a .gem file.

So what to do?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you get when you do `gem install`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do `gem build whatever.gemspec` inside of the directory that you untar/unzip -- that will produce a `.gem` file, then do `gem install whatever.gem`.

You need to be at the directory where you unzip the gem file for example

```
C:\railsinstaller\ruby2.2.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems> gem install rails-5.0.0.1.gem
```

and that's it - you are done downloading and installing Rails.

Comment: Thanks.

And this gem install whatever.gme

but that hangs for me and does nothing

Comment: WARNING:  RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for:
 

RubyGems will revert to legacy indexes degrading performance.
Bulk updating Gem source index for: http://gems.rubyforge.org/

That is the error i get

Comment: BTW - I just fixed the error in the comment above. Use a proxy or change your connection to a different source. This probably won't affect people in the 1st world, But I'm in China and this was absolutely a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the `gem build` step, and to always run the actual code, bundler can install from a local path:

```
gem 'pry', path: './pry'
```

in a Gemfile.

... where `./pry` would be the clone of your repository.

Simply run `bundle install` once, and any changes in the gem sources you make are immediately reflected. With `gem build pry / gem install pry/pry.gem`, the sources are still moved into GEM_PATH and you'll always have to run both `gem build pry` and `gem update` again if you make changes.