# Install a ruby gem from a local repository

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a git repository locally which contain a SDK project in ruby. I want to install the gem file from this local repo. It has the gemfile and gemspec files as well. Please help me on this. I tried to find a solution online but all of them are for .gem file which is locally stored not for a repo it self.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Gem Locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864618/install-gem-locally)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In your local repository:

```
gem build yourlocalrepo.gemspec
```

This will create a `.gem` file.
Now:

```
gem install yourlocalrepo.gem
```

Answer (score 2):

If your SDK project's gem was initialized by `bundle gem` command, the modern way for starting a gem, then the gem project would be configured so that the basic gem related tasks are available through the `rake` command of the project.

Namely, in my gem project I can execute

```
rake install:local
```

to build the gem being developed and install the artifact to local system.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `gem install` from the directory your gem is located. It will search the current directory first. This is from the gem references:

> gem install will install the named gem. It will attempt a local
>   installation (i.e. a .gem file in the current directory), and if that
>   fails, it will attempt to download and install the most recent version
>   of the gem you want.