# Installing rails is failing: Unable to download data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to install rails on a new machine and am running to the following command issue:

```
gem install rails
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from http://gems.rubyforge.org/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) (http://gems.rubyforge.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: I think it might have to do with downloading from gems.rubyforge.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RubyForge was down today. :)

See [here](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/24984286-08-01-2013-Failures-Running-Chef-and-Deployments?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonuKrJc%2b/hmjTEU5z14ugtW6a2lMI/0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4ATsJjPa%2bTFAwTG5toziV8R7THLs1tzt0QXhLn).

Comment: do you know where else i can get the rails gem?

Comment: If you download it from there, then you can install it locally like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220176/how-can-i-install-local-gem

Comment: I'm actually looking for 3.2.13

Answer (score 9):

`rubyforge.org` was deprecated in favor of `rubygems.org`  -- quite a while ago, this is nothing new.  But you are stuck with an old source, i was too, just updated.

You probably want to do the following, first remove rubyforge.org as a source:

```
gem source -r http://gems.rubyforge.org
```

Next add rubygems.org as a source

```
gem source -a http://rubygems.org
```

Now do a gem update:

```
gem update --system
```

Check to see which version of `gem` you are running:

```
gem -v
```

Should be on 2.0.6 (or greater).

Good to go!

Comment: Thank you! This problem has plagued me for a year and after having removed both rubyforge and rails sources, the gem script now functions once again. Can't express how glad I am for having this plague cured :)

Answer (score 1):

You could not reach the gems server. Could be many things but you can find the status of RubyForge here: http://status.rubygems.org/

Comment: This is actually the status page for `rubygems` NOT `rubyforge`.