# Ruby -- Programmatically Install Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am somewhat new to ruby, and some of the times I have used it, I can not install Gems via the `gem` program. Looking through the ruby docs, I noticed that Ruby has a library for gems in its core. I also noticed that you can download a gem directly as a `.gem` file. Is there someway I can use ruby code to extract and install a gem. This would be extremely helpful seeming as programs like RailsInstaller seem to always be outdated.

Comment: Why can't you install gems using the `gem` command in the first place ?

Comment: I don't know, at home it works, but other places, it times out.

Comment: Maybe your gem is just a bit outdated? Try `gem update --system` to install the last version.

Comment: @James_Parsons, If it is failing to install from your office, ask your IT department about the proxies they have. They might be blocking it.

Comment: And you are connected to the internet at those places?

Comment: I think @Rahul is right, the proxies may be blocking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, how about you download the .gem and install it locally using `gem install`?  Check out: "[How can I install a local gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220176/how-can-i-install-a-local-gem)"