# how can I install gem from source on local machine?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have downloaded a gem source from a private repository to my local machine, how can I install it from the source?

Comment: You can just point :git to your local, like: ` gem 'redcarpet', :git => '/home/user/library' `

Comment: @LuísBianchin I did that it yells that it is a directory !  gem 'lucymar', :git => '/home/mark/git/lucymar/'
bash: /home/mark/git/lucymar/: Is a directory

Comment: Use :path instead of :git

Comment: Another way you can do is ` gem install /full/path/to/your.gem `. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220176/how-can-i-install-a-local-gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the full source code no need to use :git notation, just go to to folder and do

```
gem build GEMNAME.gemspec
gem install gemname-version.gem
```