# Ruby on Rails error during installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to install Ruby, I followed the installation guide well, but when I tried to run the server by the command:
`ruby bin/rails setup`
after I created the controller called blog as described in the instructions, it gave me an error in red and a text in yellow:
Error:
`Could not find gem uglifier <>= 1.3.0 in the gems available on the machine.`

Yes! I know that this is a Googleable question but all I can get are solutions for people with internet access on their PC.

But unfortunately, my computer doesn't have a working Internet connection. I'm posting this question from my phone. So I'm unable to install uglifier(if that's the required thing to do) through the command prompt. Many thanks.

Comment: can you try bundle exec rails <command>

Comment: You can't install it without internet connection. If you still want to install it, then install it on some other device and transfer it to this PC with USB.

Comment: @AwaisShafqat Can you show us your source which says that or a little explanation at least?

Comment: mzcoxfde you should download the gem file (file with ".gem") some way(mobile phone maybe ?) and then copy it to the computer, you can find how to install a gem from a file  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220176/how-can-i-install-a-local-gem)

Comment: I have to say though you might struggle with gems latter because of "oh I didn't know I should download that" So getting internet or telling some friend to do it is better

Comment: @BenJunior  you want source for this?? installation of gem without internet?

Comment: ....  the simplest answer (by a longshot) is going to be "get your internet connection working".  There are ways to dance around that, but they're all going to have headaches involved.

Answer (score 0):

Please could you check if your Gemfile has the following gem

`gem 'uglifier'`

If the Gem is not present add it to your Gemfile, if you already have it in your Gemfile please run:

`bundle install`

After that you should check if the bundler is installing the uglifier gem.

Hope that helps,

Comment: the OP says he doesn't have internet connection :)

Comment: Yes it's true, but I think it will be difficult for him to install gem by gem without internet connection :)