# "gem install dashing" failing - Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have this problem since the past week, I tried to do: 
gem install dashing but i got : 
 **Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name  (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)**

I have tried a number of (rather dated) solutions on the web but they seem to be directed at trying to get past some issue.
What do I need to do to get this working? I'm using ruby 2.0.0 and gem 2.0.14.1 .

Comment: Dashing is no longer maintained, so you might consider using something else instead, https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/711

Comment: I'm obligated to work with dashing, and this isn't the problem.

Comment: Works fine for me, probably could be a case of your firewall blocking rubygems.org. Try pinging rubygems.org to eliminate this possibility.

Comment: $ curl https://rubygems.org
 curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'rubygems.org'

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it sounds like you can't reach rubygems.org. Obviously fixing that would be the ideal solution. But you can also install directly from [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing) by adding this line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'dashing', :git => 'https://github.com/Shopify/dashing'
```

For more information see [How can I install a local gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220176/how-can-i-install-a-local-gem)