# How to install fluentd plugins on No network(offline)

Tags: fluentd

I want to install `fluent-plugin-route`, but I don't know how.
i can't use `gem install fluent-plugin-route` because there's no internet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gem install file system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/220176/5030709). You will need to pre-download the `.gem` files from [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/downloads/fluent-plugin-route-1.0.0.gem) and package it with the your agent deployment and run the gem commands which should pick gem from file system. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Build the package with rake and install it with gem

1) git clone "Your Repository"

2) bundle install

- If you don't have bundler "gem install bundler"

3) bundle exec rake build

4) gem install pkg/xxx.gem (Location would be pkg folder)

Copy paste your gem via gem install --local as mentioned by DeeChok on your offline VM via gem produced on your online VM by following step 1-4

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the gem and its dependencies (also gems)

   2. Put them on the node/instance/vm
   3. Change directory to where the gems are located
   4. Run the below command:

```
gem install -N --conservative --minimal-deps --no-document --force --local *gem
```

N.B: You will have to have ruby installed. You can do that install ruby from source by following the steps [here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#rvm). You may need to install gcc, gcc-c++, openssl-dev(OR libel-dev on RHEL7) before hand.

Hope this helps :)