# Is there a way to install a rubygem manually without accessing rubygems.org?

Tags: console, rubygems, jekyll, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So i have this IPv6 thingy issue where i can't access rubygems and connection times out before it gets to use IPv4. One way or another i managed to install rubygems and when i type -v it all checks out. Now i need Jekyll and Jekyll-paginate-v2. I tried `gem install jekyll` and it didn't work for reasons stated above. Strangely enough i was able to install Jekyll via `sudo apt install jekyll`. Tried that with jekyll-paginate-v2 but there's no such option. So is there any way to install it without using `gem` command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220176/how-can-i-install-a-local-gem is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam no but kinda yes. in order to use this solution i would have to fetch a .gem file from rubygems first so it's kinda the same but i found a workaround - i built a gem using github and then installed it. thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i found a way of solving this issue.

to install a gem you need a .gem file and since you can't access rubygems.org we will get it from github. just go to your gem's github page, download it and then open bash in that directory, type `gem build gemname.gemspec` and it will create a .gem file in this directory. after that just use `gem install --local gemname.gem` and that's it.

Comment: Please mark this answer as the accepted answer (even if its your own answer) so that new visitors need not bother attempting to help.